# move_uploaded_file не работает с конкретным файлом

Tags: php, mysql

Вот кусок скрипта:

```
$path_to_90_directory = 'avatars/';//папка, куда будет загружаться начальная картинка и ее сжатая копия

if(preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(gif)|(GIF)|(png)|(PNG)$/',$_FILES['fupload']['name']))//проверка формата исходного изображения
     {

        $filename = $_FILES['fupload']['name'];
        $source = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'];   
        $target = $path_to_90_directory . $filename;
        move_uploaded_file($source, $target);//загрузка оригинала в папку $path_to_90_directory

    if(preg_match('/[.](GIF)|(gif)$/', $filename)) {
    $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_90_directory.$filename) ; //если оригинал был в формате gif, то создаем изображение в этом же формате. Необходимо для последующего сжатия
    }
    if(preg_match('/[.](PNG)|(png)$/', $filename)) {
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_90_directory.$filename) ;//если оригинал был в формате png, то создаем изображение в этом же формате. Необходимо для последующего сжатия
    }

    if(preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(JPEG)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_90_directory.$filename); //если оригинал был в формате jpg, то создаем изображение в этом же формате. Необходимо для последующего сжатия
    }
```

**Он работал со всеми изображениями, которые я когда-либо обрабатывал. Но сегодня мне попалась фотография, которая просто постоянно выдает ошибку. 165 строчка это как раз выполнение move_uploaded_file. Возможно у кого-либо возникала подобная проблема, помогите разобраться.**

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(avatars/14012013768.JPG) [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Z:\home\relax.ru\www\save_user.php on line 165

Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in Z:\home\relax.ru\www\save_user.php on line 175

Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in Z:\home\relax.ru\www\save_user.php on line 176

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(avatars/14012013768.JPG) [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Z:\home\relax.ru\www\save_user.php on line 196

Warning: getimagesize(avatars/14012013768.JPG) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Z:\home\relax.ru\www\save_user.php on line 199

Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in Z:\home\relax.ru\www\save_user.php on line 206

Warning: unlink(avatars/14012013768.JPG) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in Z:\home\relax.ru\www\save_user.php on line 219

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нафига столько preg_match?  Есть функция getimagesize().. Если она возвращает false, то это не картинка..
Дальше проще..

```
$img_data = getimagesize($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
switch($img_data['mime']) {
    case 'image/jpeg':     
        /* JPEG image */
        break;
    case 'image/png':
        /* PNG image */
        break;
    /* и т.д. */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Первое, что приходит на ум - файл все-таки не был загружен нормально.

> Warning:
> getimagesize(avatars/14012013768.JPG)
> [function.getimagesize]: failed to
> open stream: No such file or directory

То есть файла на нужном месте нет, остальное - это уже последствия.

Кроме того:

1. `preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(JPEG)$/', $filename)` - это жуть. А если расширение будет `jPeG`?
2. не рекомендуется сохранять файлы от юзеров под их оригинальными именами